# JavaScript - Hide all divs by class and show one by ID

Tags: javascript, html

I need a JavaScript function that will allow me to change "display" property for one element to block but keep the others set to none (they are on top one another). Click image1 = display content1, but when you click image2, set content1 back to invisible and display content2 only.

```html
<div id="imagesContainer">
  <img id="image0" onclick="function()">
  <img id="image1" onclick="function()">
  <img id="image2" onclick="function()">
  <img id="image3" onclick="function()">
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="content0">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well nothing much, since I can't seem to figure out the right logic to use. I was thinking about a JS switch, but I can't figure out how to extract the right content ID based on the <img> ID I click. I am not even sure if that is the right angle to approach it, I'm completely lost

Comment: Please share complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a little **improvement** of First dev's answer

html

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
      <img id="image0" onclick="disp(0)">
      <img id="image1" onclick="disp(1)">
      <img id="image2" onclick="disp(2)">
      <img id="image3" onclick="disp(3)">
    </div>
    <div id="contentContainer">
      <div id="content0" class="co">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div id="content1" class="co">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div id="content2" class="co">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div id="content3" class="co">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
```

js

```
var  content= document.getElementsByClassName('co');

for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i ++) {
    content[i].style.display = 'none';
}
function disp(a){
    document.getElementById('content'+a).style.display='block';
    for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i ++) {
        if(i!=a)
        content[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Used this, it's simple and clean, works like a charm! Thank you everybody

Answer (score 0):

JS

```
function disp(a){
    document.getElementById('content0').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('content1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('content2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('content3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('content'+a).style.display='block';
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="imagesContainer">
  <img id="image0" onclick="disp(0)">
  <img id="image1" onclick="disp(1)">
  <img id="image2" onclick="disp(2)">
  <img id="image3" onclick="disp(3)">
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="content0">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div id="content3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, used the simplified version from @Marius98

Answer (score 0):

Solution using `forEach()`:

EDIT - Just realised that in the original post, the code does not include classes, which the title of the question refers to. So this example mistakenly works only with IDs.

```js
// Array of unique suffixes used for images and content
var availableIds = '0 1 2 3'.split( ' ' );

function showContent( imageId ) {

  var selectedId = imageId.replace( 'image', '' );

  availableIds.forEach(function _showContent_forEach( availableId ) {

    var displayBlock = selectedId === availableId;
    var contentId = 'content' + availableId;

    document.getElementById( contentId )
      .style.display = displayBlock ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
}

showContent( '0' ); // Default
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="imagesContainer">
  <img id="image0" onclick="showContent( this.id )">
  <img id="image1" onclick="showContent( this.id )">
  <img id="image2" onclick="showContent( this.id )">
  <img id="image3" onclick="showContent( this.id )">
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
  <div id="content0">Lorem Ipsum 1</div>
  <div id="content1">Lorem Ipsum 2</div>
  <div id="content2">Lorem Ipsum 3</div>
  <div id="content3">Lorem Ipsum 4</div>
</div>
```